# django markdownx isn't allowing normal html tags

Tags: html, django, markdown, markup, django-markdown-deux

I added django-markdownx to my project. Everything is working fine with this custom filter:

```
import markdown
@register.filter
def markdownify(text):
    return markdown.markdown(text, safe_mode='escape')
```

This is converting markdown to HTML but if the file contains normal HTML it will convert the markdown successfully but not the normal HTML.

This is how I use the filter:

```
{{ Post.body|markdownify|safe|linebreaks }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `safe_mode='escape'` to `markdown.markdown`, which tells the Markdown parser to "escape" raw HTML in the Markdown text. Remove the `safe_mode` parameter and raw HTML will be preserved in your output:

```
import markdown
@register.filter
def markdownify(text):
    return markdown.markdown(text)
```